DeepFace module export to disk, How?
I have being trying to use DeepFace module in python, to detect live video face with a photo, for which i used this Python code
import cv2
from deepface import DeepFace


# URL of the phone's camera stream (update this with your actual URL)
stream_url = "http://192.168.77.141:8080/video"

# Open the video stream
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(stream_url)

if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Error: Could not open video stream.")
    exit()

# Preload the DeepFace model to avoid delays
DeepFace.build_model("VGG-Face")



while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if not ret:
        print("Error: Could not read frame.")
        break

    
    try:
        match = DeepFace.verify("manas2.jpg", frame, enforce_detection=False)
        print(match['verified'])
        if match['verified']:
            print("Matched !!")
            break
    except ValueError as e:
        print(f"Face verification failed: {e}")


    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Phone Camera Stream', frame)


    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release the capture when done
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


However it is taking time to load and then start matching face with frames (around 10-13 seconds).
I first thought of saving this model to disk, but it didn't worked.
from deepface import DeepFace
import tensorflow as tf

model = DeepFace.build_model("VGG-Face")



model.save("vgg_face_model.h5")

Can anyone please help me how can I do this, If possible any other better way to perform same.
My main goal is to make a program in python that takes a picture and then checks video live using webcam and give output as whether the person is same or not.
Thankyou in Advance.

Have you used a profiler to see what's taking so long within the DeepFace.build_model("VGG-Face") call? Of course assuming that's where the time is being spent.

Tensorflow loading model was taking time around 4-5 seconds before starting to print matches. I just want to get rid of that loading time...

VGG-Face has 136M params (weights and biases). It is too normal to take time when you load it. Does not matter if you save it to filesystem. You have to wait it until loaded. You already put it before the while loop. You may consider to use Facenet model. It offers same level accuracy but it has 22M params. In other words, it is 6x times smaller.
